# Swift: Start ble scan from beacon wake

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, beacon

have an application that is wake by an ibeacon, the application is wake it starts a scan.

When the screen is off the scan not seem to work, that I turn on the screen the scan the scan return results.
I understand the scan does not work if the screen is off. How to make Start Scan via Beacon advertisement?

I think before that worked, I am on ios 15. I did not check on iOS14, but on iOS 13 the scan worked when the screen was off, I just did not have access to advertisement data

Comment: Please show your code.  It is unclear if you are using beacon ranging or monitoring.  Monitoring works with the screen off but only if you have location “always” permission.  Ranging does not work for long with the screen off.  This is unchanged in iOS15.

Comment: It's complicated to show the code is an entire project, I set also ranging and monitoring for region.
But I can say that the `DidrangeBeacon` is always called even when the screen is off.
So the Beacon wakes the application and start The ble scan but the `Diddiscoverperipheral` was not called IF Screen Off.
What I had to do is when the Beacon wakes the application, I start ble Scan, then send a local notification for turning ON the screen and there `Diddiscoverperipheral` was called and return the peripheral.
I have a ble device who share Beacon with his advertisement.

Comment: This is nothing new in iOS 15:  didDiscoverPeripheral callbacks are limited to when the screen is on unless the advertisement has a 128-bit service UUID.    I note this limitation in my blog post here, written when iOS 13 was new: http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2020/05/07/hacking-the-overflow-area

Comment: So if I understand it well since IOS 13 when the screen is off, `DiddiscoverPheral` is not called. I remember that before iOS 13 the callback was called but we had not access to advertisement data when the screen is off.

Comment: On all recent versions of iOS `didDiscoverPeripheral` is called in the background with the screen off only under the following conditions:  (1) a specific Service UUID is included in the scan (2) the detection comes from a standard service advertisement from a hardware BLE peripheral or a foregrounded iOS device.  (3) The screen is on and the advertisement comes from a different backgrounded iOS device acting as a peripheral.  Further, when the screen is off, the scanning iOS device looking for specific Service UUIDs will only get **one** callback per unique device detected.

Comment: This in the case of app is in background. But in the case of the application is **killed**, the screen is off, and the scanning of the app was started from beacon advertisement recognition, it's look like that `didDiscoverPeripheral` not called at all, and if at the same time I turn the screen on suddenly `didDiscoverPeripheral` was called. Have you tested this case?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get bluetooth events in the background, you need to make sure your Info.plist declares this:

```
        <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
        <array>
           <string>bluetooth-central</string>
        </array>
```

If that is not present, you absolutely will not get callbacks to `didDiscoverPeripheral` in the background.

Comment: In simple background it works. It does not work if the app (**Killed**) is launched by iBeacon and screen Off.

Comment: You can try this:
An application that detects an ibeacon, when beacon is detected is `startscanforperipheralswithuuids`. Now that we have this app check in the settings that location permission is set`Always`.

Comment: When is done, kills the application totally by swipe up. Turn Screen Off. Patient 40 seconds, and with a Beacon Transmitter Share Beacon advertisement.
You will see the app wake up, but the scan will not work. For debug when the app is killed with screen I print logs in a phone file. Don't send local notification to turn screen on

Comment: And if for you everything works, please share you code in git

Comment: From your tests are, you saying you see the scan starts working as soon as the screen turns on the first time after the app is killed and scanning was started from the background?

Comment: Exactly, as long as the screen is off `Diddiscoverperipheral` is not called, if the application is **killed**, (start scan from beacon wake up)